# Restore Permanently deleted work items in Azure DevOps services

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any option to restore the permanently deleted work items in Azure DevOps services?

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for developers to ask questions when they run into snags while developing software. This question feels like it fits better on either Superuser or Microsoft Q&A. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

> WARNING: If the destroy parameter is set to true, work items deleted by this command will NOT go to recycle-bin and there is no way to restore/recover them after deletion.

This is related to the REST API but is the same for UI action and command-line tool.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Yan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70741259/1945525):

If you permanently deleted work items by choosing Destroy, then no:

> Destroy: Permanently delete work items, *deleting all data from the work tracking data store*.

Source: [Remove, delete, or restore work items in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops)